# How do I make Speedment regenerate code automatically on build

Tags: java, speedment

I have a Speedment project set up but I do not want to run the GUI Tool and I do not want to check in the generated files in my software repository (GIT). How can I make Speedment automatically regenerate all code on build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pom.xml` file, add an execution tag to the `speedment-maven-plugin` like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.speedment</groupId>
        <artifactId>speedment-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${speedment.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>Generate code automatically</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>        
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This only solves part of the question. To prevent generated code from being checked in, the folder with the generated code need to be excluded in the .gitignore file.